# Como interceptar o resultado de uma query?

Tags: php, pdo

Preciso testar se a query feita correu tudo bem ou se ouve algum erro. Ja procurei porem não achei algo que satisfaze-se o que preciso.

Exemplo:

Submeti uma sql no banco, e ela foi feita corretamente, porém ouve um erro no campo numero, na sql de insert ele foi vazio. O `Try/catch` não consegirá pegar o erro, pois foi submetido porém não foi efetivada.

Preciso saber isto, se ela foi efetivada ou não.

No caso de ser um UPDATE e DELE `mysql_affected_rows` funciona perfeitamente, ele retornará as linhas afetadas bastando fazer um `if` se for `>0` foi bem sucedido se não, ouve algum erro.

Comment: Poste a quey na pergunta.

Comment: Pode ser qualquer uma. De insert, de delete, de uptade, qualquer query. so preciso saber se ela foi sucedida ou não

Comment: Olhe seu campo no mysql se esta com `not null` o PHP não acusou "erro" porque provavelmente este campo aceita "dados null"

Comment: @RafaelAcioly Você não entendeu o que eu quero. Estou precisando saber se existe algum mecanismo para saber se houve erro na sql inserida, ou se tudo correu bem. O caso do numero é apenas um exemplo que dei para entender o que quero.

Comment: @RenanRodrigues quando você executa uma query ela retorna automaticamente `true` ou `false`, use um `if` caso queira confirmar a execução! se voce diz em aparecer erro no navegador então procure sobre habilitar o erro no php.ini e usar o `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Comment: Então isso não é interceptar, você quer checar se a query foi executada conforme o esperado pela aplicação, ainda sim, a query pode ser executada sem erros, mas não como o esperado pela aplicação. E você mesmo respondeu a sua pergunta nas linhas finais, apesar de citar PDO na tag e a função que você exemplificou não tem nad a ver com PDO.

Comment: Olhe essa resposta no Soen. -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/11820939/5524514

Comment: `mysqli_error($conexao)` ou `$conexao->error`são as responsáveis por armazenar e retornar erros numa consulta, caso existam. Existem também outras funções responsáveis pelos erros, veja [isto](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php).

Comment: `mysqli_error($conexao)`? a pergunta tem a tag PDO, a menos que tenha entendido errado.

Comment: É PDO mesmo, mais ja consegui resolver isto, obrigado a todos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao utilizar prepared statements com o PDO, verifique o retorno do `execute()` e claro defina no construtor do PDO que os erros devem ser tratados como exceptions.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
if(!$stmt->execute()){
   print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
}else{
   echo 'sucesso';
}
```

Com execptions:

```
$opcoes = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=catalogo', 'root', 'root');

try{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```